# flexbox center multiple items horizontally weird image

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to put text next to an icon in a container.
The height of the container gets determined by the first image element.
On this image element i put a container with some content inside (a icon and text)
But the icon gets stretched...
See below:

```css
#scan_image {
  margin: 30px 0 5px 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#scan_image img {
  width: 100%;
}

#scan_image_content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#scan_image_content img {
  height: 70%;
}

#scan_image_content h2 {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="scan_image">
  <img src="https://www.collegevanrijksadviseurs.nl/binaries/large/content/gallery/college-van-rijksadviseurs/content-afbeeldingen/projecten/panorama-nederland/01.jpg">
  <div id="scan_image_content" class="wiggle">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Approve_icon.svg">
    <h2>ESCANEAR PÁGINA</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sort of the desired effect:
[image]

Comment: it's not very clear to me do you want to center the (icon + text ) container and let them take their height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this selector `#scan_image img` apply a 100% width for all image inside of it including your icon, so you need to specify a width for the backgrounder adding a class for it.

```
#scan_image {
    margin: 30px 0 5px 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#scan_image .img {
    width: 100%;
}

#scan_image_content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;  // to align the items vertically 
}

#scan_image_content img {
    height: 70%;
}

#scan_image_content h2 {
    color: #000;
}
```

and adding .img class in the HTML file :

```
<div id="scan_image">
  <img src="https://www.collegevanrijksadviseurs.nl/binaries/large/content/gallery/college-van-rijksadviseurs/content-afbeeldingen/projecten/panorama-nederland/01.jpg" class="img">
  <div id="scan_image_content" class="wiggle">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Approve_icon.svg">
    <h2>ESCANEAR PÁGINA</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and explaination! But i forgot to mention that i need the image in the flexbox to be 70% the height of the container.. thats why the `height:70%` How would i go about doing this>

Comment: the height still 70%, the only thing checked is the width become 70px instead of 100% which is a full width

Comment: ah i see, but i need to preserve the aspect ratio of the image.  with width 70px this is not always the case. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: aha I can see, to do what you want you should edit this selector `#scan_image img` by adding a class or id for it and remove the wish from the icon, I'll add modifications

Answer (score 0):

Please add the html and css and see if it works

```
<div id="scan_image">
   <img src="https://www.collegevanrijksadviseurs.nl/binaries/large/content/gallery/college-van-rijksadviseurs/content-afbeeldingen/projecten/panorama-nederland/01.jpg">
   <div id="scan_image_content" class="wiggle">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Approve_icon.svg">
     <div>
        <h2>FIRST LINE</h2>
        <h2>SECOND LINE</h2>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>


#scan_image_content img {
 width: auto 
}

#scan_image_content {
align-items: center;
}
```

[image]